# No sound is captured in video created using FFmpegFrameGrabber, FrameRecorder JavaCv in android

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, javacv

I am trying to apply Grayscale effect to a video file using **JavaCV** in android.Everything is working fine but there is no audio present in the output file. Below is the code. Please Help

```
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test3.mp4"); 

     FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(file.getAbsolutePath()); 

     FrameRecorder recorder = null; 

     Log.d("bharat", " Audio channels = " + frameGrabber.getAudioChannels()); // THIS IS RETurnING 0 and not 2

     recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("/mnt/sdcard/streaml_t.mp4", 270, 480, frameGrabber.getAudioChannels()); 

     recorder.setVideoCodec(AV_CODEC_ID_H264); 

     recorder.setFormat("mp4"); 

     recorder.setFrameRate(frameGrabber.getFrameRate()); 

     recorder.setSampleFormat(frameGrabber.getSampleFormat()); 

     recorder.setSampleRate(frameGrabber.getSampleRate()); 

     try { 
     recorder.start();
     frameGrabber.start(); 
     int count = 0;      
     while (true) { 

     try { 

     Frame grabFrame = frameGrabber.grabFrame(); 
     Log.d("bharat:", "frame " + count++); 

     if (grabFrame == null) { 
     System.out.println("!!! Failed cvQueryFrame"); 
     break; 

     } 

     IplImage frame_copy = cvCreateImage(cvSize(grabFrame.image.width(), grabFrame.image.height()), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 

     cvCvtColor(grabFrame.image, frame_copy, CV_RGB2GRAY); 
     grabFrame.image = frame_copy; 
     recorder.setTimestamp(frameGrabber.getTimestamp());
     recorder.record(grabFrame); 
     } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
     } 

     } 

     Log.d("bharat:", "frame done"); 

     recorder.stop(); 
     recorder.release(); 

     } catch (Exception e) { 

     e.printStackTrace(); 

     } 

     }
```

P. S :  I found that frameGrabber.getAudioChannels() is returning 0 and not 2 (in case it helps)

Answer (score 1):

Once I [met](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=409#c3) a problem due to lack of docs in JavaCV like:

```
/**  Grab next videoframe */
public IplImage grab() 
/** Grab next video or audio frame */
public Frame grabFrame()
```

So you get audio or video frame and then you always try to process this as image. You should check is it audio or video frame before and don't try to call cvCvtColor() for audio.

Comment: Thanks @Vit Shiryaev but I got the answer. I was actually using javaCV 0.7 and it was not working. I then updated to javaCV 0.9 and its working now. thanks